# Update with SQL cursor, with variable at the end

Tags: sql, sql-update, cursor

I have a question about updating a SQL table with cursor. For specific products, I know the today stock, and for every day how many will come in and how many will go out. Now I need to calculate the expected stock for future days.

In this picture is an example:

So today we have 78 pieces and nothing will happen. Tomorrow, 35 are going out, so actual stock should change to 43. But the day after that, 57 will go out, so stock needs to change from 43 to -14 (43-57). So after every row, the stock must be updated.

I think I need a cursor for this, I am already trying a few days but's it's not working at all.

[See table][image: 1]

This is my current query for the cursor:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @date int;
DECLARE @product varchar(max);
DECLARE @current_stock int;
DECLARE @incoming int;
DECLARE @outgoing int;
DECLARE @day_stock int;

DECLARE stock_cursor cursor for
SELECT date, product, current_stock, incoming, outgoing, day_stock FROM stock_table order by date asc

Open stock_cursor;
fetch next from stock_cursor into @date, @product, @current_stock, @incoming, @outgoing, @day_stock
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN


UPDATE stock_table
SET day_stock = current_stock + incoming - outgoing
WHERE CURRENT OF stock_cursor


fetch next from stock_cursor into @date, @product, @current_stock, @incoming, @outgoing, @day_stock
end
close stock_cursor;
deallocate stock_cursor;
end
```

First of all, it's saying: 'The cursor is READ ONLY.' But I need to order by date because the date ordering is important for the sequence of the update.

But most important, it's not using the last known stock, for updating with the incoming and outgoing numbers to create a new day_stock. Really don't know what to change here.

Can someone help me out or see what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Declare the cursor `FOR UPDATE`.

Comment: Thanks, I added: FOR UPDATE OF day_stock

The problem is: I want every new row to start with the result of the previous row.

Comment: Stock balances should be calculated when needed based on raw data records, not saved to table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for a cursor (rarely is there ever a need for a cursor ;-)

All you appear to be doing is mainting a running total - this is something a database can do in its sleep!

You can easily add a running total using sum over()

Saying that, this is not a particularly good design, I would suggest a separate inventory to store the current stock value for each product :-)

```
create table X ([Date] date, Product uniqueidentifier, CurrentStock int, Incoming int, Outgoing int)

insert into X select '20210306', 'B1A761BF-7897-41D9-AAD8-DF6D8832B877', 78, 0, 0
insert into X select '20210307', 'B1A761BF-7897-41D9-AAD8-DF6D8832B877', 78, 0, 35
insert into X select '20210308', 'B1A761BF-7897-41D9-AAD8-DF6D8832B877', 78, 0, 57
insert into X select '20210309', 'B1A761BF-7897-41D9-AAD8-DF6D8832B877', 78, 0, 14
insert into X select '20210310', 'B1A761BF-7897-41D9-AAD8-DF6D8832B877', 78, 0, 2
insert into X select '20210311', 'B1A761BF-7897-41D9-AAD8-DF6D8832B877', 78, 0, 24
insert into X select '20210312', 'B1A761BF-7897-41D9-AAD8-DF6D8832B877', 78, 0, 24
insert into X select '20210313', 'B1A761BF-7897-41D9-AAD8-DF6D8832B877', 78, 0, 0
insert into X select '20210314', 'B1A761BF-7897-41D9-AAD8-DF6D8832B877', 78, 0, 0
insert into X select '20210315', 'B1A761BF-7897-41D9-AAD8-DF6D8832B877', 78, 0, 53
insert into X select '20210316', 'B1A761BF-7897-41D9-AAD8-DF6D8832B877', 78, 12, 0
```

Additional example data for different product

```
insert into X select '20210308', '09334B58-EAB8-4C44-80C6-B87B5E4DDC01', 50, 6, 4
insert into X select '20210309', '09334B58-EAB8-4C44-80C6-B87B5E4DDC01', 50, 0, 1
insert into X select '20210310', '09334B58-EAB8-4C44-80C6-B87B5E4DDC01', 50, 0, 10

select *, 
    currentstock - sum(Outgoing) over(partition by Product order by [Date]) + sum(Incoming) over(partition by Product order by [Date]) DayStock
from X
where product='B1A761BF-7897-41D9-AAD8-DF6D8832B877'
order by [date]
```

Result

```
Date       Product                                CurrentStock    Incoming    Outgoing    DayStock
---------- -------------------------------------- ------------ ----------- ----------- -----------
2021-03-06 "B1A761BF-7897-41D9-AAD8-DF6D8832B877"           78           0           0          78
2021-03-07 "B1A761BF-7897-41D9-AAD8-DF6D8832B877"           78           0          35          43
2021-03-08 "B1A761BF-7897-41D9-AAD8-DF6D8832B877"           78           0          57         -14
2021-03-09 "B1A761BF-7897-41D9-AAD8-DF6D8832B877"           78           0          14         -28
2021-03-10 "B1A761BF-7897-41D9-AAD8-DF6D8832B877"           78           0           2         -30
2021-03-11 "B1A761BF-7897-41D9-AAD8-DF6D8832B877"           78           0          24         -54
2021-03-12 "B1A761BF-7897-41D9-AAD8-DF6D8832B877"           78           0          24         -78
2021-03-13 "B1A761BF-7897-41D9-AAD8-DF6D8832B877"           78           0           0         -78
2021-03-14 "B1A761BF-7897-41D9-AAD8-DF6D8832B877"           78           0           0         -78
2021-03-15 "B1A761BF-7897-41D9-AAD8-DF6D8832B877"           78           0          53        -131
2021-03-16 "B1A761BF-7897-41D9-AAD8-DF6D8832B877"           78          12           0        -119
```

Comment: thanks very much! This totally worked for me and gave me new insights. I build my solution like you said and it's working perfect. Thanks for this great help!